# Merge 2 regex patterns

Tags: regex

I have a text file that contains something like this (this is only on excerpt):

```
Third Doctor
Season 7
051 Spearhead from Space    4   3—24 January 1970
052 Doctor Who and the Silurians    7   31 January—14 March 1970
053 The Ambassadors of Death    7   21 March—2 May 1970
054 Inferno 7   9 May—20 June 1970

Season 8
055 Terror of the Autons    4   2—23 January 1971
056 The Mind of Evil    6   30 January—6 March 1971
057 The Claws of Axos   4   13 March—3 April 1971
058 Colony in Space 6   10 April—15 May 1971
059 The Dæmons  5   22 May—19 June 1971
```

Note that the basic line pattern is `^###\t.*\t?\t.*$` (i.e almost every line has 3 tabs `\t`).

I would like to remove everything after the the episode title, so that it would look like this:

```
Third Doctor
Season 7
051 Spearhead from Space
052 Doctor Who and the Silurians
053 The Ambassadors of Death
054 Inferno

Season 8
055 Terror of the Autons
056 The Mind of Evil
057 The Claws of Axos
058 Colony in Space
059 The Dæmons
```

Currently I tested the following patterns in gedit:

```
([^\t]*)$   # replaces not only everything after the last `\t',
            # incl that `\t', but also lines that *does not* contain any `\t'
```

Then I tried to ‘make a selection’ of the lines, which should be regexed by `(?=(?=^(?:(?!Season).)*$)(?=^(?:(?!Series).)*$)(?=^(?:(?!Doctor$).)*$)(?=^(?:(?!Title).)*$)(?=^(?:(?!Specials$).)*$)(?=^(?:(?!Mini).)*$)(?=^(?:(?!^\t).)*$)(?=^(?:(?!Anim).)*$)).*$` — this *does* work as intended, BUT I do not know how to combine it with `([^\t]*)$`.

Comment: @vks: I would say bash, but don’t really know what kinda regex does gedit 3.10.4 use :) … But bash (sed) regex is good enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is fields separated by tabs, you only need to use `cut` to obtain the two first fields:

```
cut -f1,2 drwho.txt
```

for the knowledge, the same with awk:

```
awk -F"\t" '$3{print $1"\t"$2}!$3{print $0}' drwho.txt
```

explanation: awk works line by line, the F parameter defines the fields delimiter.

```
$3 {                   # if field3 exists
    print $1"\t"$2     # display field1, a tab, field2
}
!$3 {                  # if field3 doesn't exist
    print $0           # display the whole record (the line)
}
```

Comment: @Casimir_et_Hippolyte: I see U know Dr Who :) … but the first code U provided does not work for me either … neither in gedit nor using `sed`. But I tried it in [regex101.com] (http://regex101.com/r/vG0aK9/1), but I left some extra chars …

Comment: @tukusejssirs: I have written a sed version.

Comment: @Casimir_et_Hippolyte: I do not know why, but this does not work neither. FYI, I use sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2.

Comment: @tukusejssirs: same version for me, are you sure that the string you have posted is the same that the original string?

Comment: @tukusejssirs: the fields of the file are probably separated by tabs. Try the awk way.

Comment: @Casimir_et_Hippolyte: I just now realised that the copied excerpt replaced all tabs by spaces and I used this excerpt to check the codes ;) … now I have checked this original file in which there are indeed tabs and the `awk` way works perfectly … The sed way still does not. Nevermind :) … But could U just explain both codes, so I could learn from it? Thanks :)

Comment: @Casimir_et_Hippolyte: Just a note. The awk way also substituted all tabs by single space. And it also left a space end the end of *some* lines.

Comment: @tukusejssirs: I have a better idea. simply use `cut`

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d{3}\s+.*?)(?=\s*\d).*$
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.Use flags `m` or `MULTILINE` depending on your flavour of regex.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jI8lV7/8

Comment: Although this does work in the demo, but neither in gedit nor in ubuntu gnome 14.10 gnome-terminal (default settings) `sed 's/^(\d{3}\s+.*?)(?=\s*\d).*$//g' file`. … As for the ‘Replace by `$1`.’ and ‘Use flags `m` or `MULTILINE`’, I need more detailed instructions, ’cos I don’ really understand :)

Comment: @tukusejssirs you can do this using python or perl.Python code would be like this.

    `import re`

    `p = re.compile(ur'^(\d{3}\s+.*?)(?=\s*\d).*$', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)`

    `test_str = <your test string>`

    `subst = u"$1"`

    `result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)`